# Good Authentication for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anyone know the best solution for Authentication in Rails 3 - that is stable and ready for a publicly released app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything I've read lately has pointed me to Devise

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Devise is the probably the best authentication solution for Rails out there.!

Comment: Devise seems better used so getting answers for it is somewhat easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Authlogic** is another option for you.
https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the best authentication-authorization solution seems to be Devise with Cancan. Great post here: http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers